# how to create Large Xlsx fie via java opi?

Tags: java, excel, xls

i have a Result Set(85000 record)
i want create xls file in java and send this file for downloading in client side!!!
but opi suport 65536 record.

HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow( int  index);
plz help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Microsoft Excel can't read more than 65536 rows, the only solution would be to split records in two files.

Or, you can switch to OpenDocument. It supports 1048576 rows, and it can be read by Microsoft Excel too. There also is an API to read/write to OpenDocument format, check [JOpenDocument](http://www.jopendocument.org/)